# The number of Hamiltonian paths in a tournament

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

> If $h(T)$ denotes the number of (directed) [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in the [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) $T,$ what is the range of $h(T)$ as $T$ ranges over all (finite) tournaments $T$?

By a classical theorem of [Rédei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_R%C3%A9dei) (László Rédei, Ein kombinatorischer Satz, *Acta Litteraria Szeged* **7** (1934), 39–43), every tournament has an odd number of Hamiltonian paths. Moreover, one can verify that there is no tournament with exactly $7$ Hamiltonian paths.

> Is there an odd number $p\gt7$ such that no tournament has exactly $p$ Hamiltonian paths?

Comment: How do you verify that there is no tournament with exactly $7$ Hamiltonian paths?

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Since $7$ is a prime number, if there is a tournament with exactly $7$ Hamiltonian paths, the smallest such tournaments must be strongly connected. A strongly connected tournament of order $n$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, whence it has at least $n$ Hamiltonian paths. Thus it suffices to consider tournaments on at most $7$ nodes. The rest is a somewhat tedious argument by cases, which I did by hand, so I may have made a mistake.

Comment: Here's a comment I can't resist making: A beautiful proof of that "classical theorem of Rédei" can be found in §10.2 (Theorem 6) of Claude Berge, *Graphs*, 3rd edition, North-Holland 1991. Another proof (that looks very much like Rédei's original) appears in §9 of John W. Moon, *Topics on Tournaments*, 2015, Project Gutenberg Release #42833 ( http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/gutbook/lookup?num=42833 ). And yet another can be found in Corollaire 5.1 of Bodo Lass, *Variations sur le thème $E+\overline{E}=XY$*, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0196-8858(02)00010-6 .

Comment: And Berge's proof of Rédei's theorem has now reappeared in my freshly-completed [notes for Math 5707 lecture 7](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/17s/5707lec7.pdf) (I kept them self-contained, since lectures 1-6 have not been digitalized).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds bizarre, but my computations suggest that 21 might be a possibility..

I checked the tournaments on up to 9 vertices (10 vertices is under way) and got the following results:

- by 6 vertices, every odd number (except 7 and 21) less than 33 had occurred at least once
- by 7 vertices, every odd number (except 7 and 21) less than 63 had occurred at least once
- by 8 vertices, every odd number (except 7 and 21) less than 611 had occurred at least once
- by 9 vertices, every odd number (except 7 and 21) less than 2883 had occurred at least once

So there is an obvious conjecture based on those numbers...

**Edit** (Additional data): By 10 vertices, every odd number (not 7, 21) less than 14685 has occurred. So now I am convinced that there is no tournament with exactly 21 hamilton paths

**Edit** (Even more additional data): By 11 vertices, every odd number (not 7, 21) less than 80557 has occurred as the number of hamiltonian paths of a tournament on at most 11 vertices.

Comment: Since there is no tournament with $7$ Hamiltonian paths, the smallest tournaments (if any) with $21$ Hamiltonian paths must be strongly connected. I don't know what is known in the way of lower bounds for the number of Hamiltonian paths in a strongly connected tournament (I asked a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688155/minimum-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-strongly-connected-tournament-on-n-no) about that on math.se) but it's easy to see that a strongly connected tournament on $8$ or more nodes must have at least $25$ Hamiltonian paths.

Comment: Thus your computations are already more than enough to show that there is no tournament with exactly $21$ Hamiltonian paths. It seems likely that $7$ and $21$ are the only missing odd numbers. I guess the smallest open case is $14693=7\cdot2099.$